# How do you rotate UIView, UIImageView or CALayer animated 360˚?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uikit, core-animation

How do you rotate `UIView`, `UIImageView` or `CALayer` animated 360 degress without using OpenGL ES?

Comment: You do realize that 360˚ rotation will give you the exact same image, right?

Comment: I find it sad that I started trying to think of a solution before I realized that.

Comment: @Steam Trout: only if you want it to be instantaneous.

Comment: Accept answer please? Or describe why it does not answer your question.

Answer (score 28):

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

CABasicAnimation *fullRotation;
fullRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
fullRotation.fromValue = @(0.0);
fullRotation.toValue = @((360.0 * M_PI)/180.0);
fullRotation.duration = 3.5f;
fullRotation.repeatCount = MAXFLOAT;

[view.layer addAnimation:fullRotation forKey:@"rotation-animation"];
```

If you want to change the anchor point it to rotates around then you can do

```
CGRect frame = view.layer.frame;
self.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5); // rotates around center
self.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you mean animate rotating a `UIImage` around a full 360°?  In my experience, the way to accomplish a full circle rotation is to chain multiple animations together:

```
- (IBAction)rotate:(id)sender
{
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"step1" context:NULL]; {
      [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
      [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
      [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
     [imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(120 * M_PI / 180);
   } [UIView commitAnimations];
}

- (void)animationDidStop:(NSString *)animationID finished:(NSNumber *)finished context:(void *)context
{
   if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"step1"]) {
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"step2" context:NULL]; {
         [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
         [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
         [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
         imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(240 * M_PI / 180);
      } [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
   else if ([animationID isEqualToString:@"step2"]) {
      [UIView beginAnimations:@"step3" context:NULL]; {
         [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
         [UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(animationDidStop:finished:context:)];
         [UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
         imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0);
      } [UIView commitAnimations];
   }
}
```

I've left the `easeIn/easeOut` curve (instead of linear) in place, so you can see the individual animations.