# How do I spin a UIImage or UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [rotate a UIView around its center but several times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/518530/rotate-a-uiview-around-its-center-but-several-times)
>   [How do you rotate a UIImage 360˚](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431776/how-do-you-rotate-a-uiimage-360)

I simply want an image to spin like a pinwheel.  My attempts with CGAffineTransformRotate or CGAffineTransformMakeRotation seem to spin the UIImageView clockwise AND end over end.

I'm just looking for clockwise spinning.

I've "assigned" an image to a UIImage and then make the UIImageView.Image equal to the UIImage.

I then use:

```
mySpinningImage.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(mySpinningImage.transform,M_PI);
```

To attempt, in vain, to have the image fluidly spin clockwise.

Help...

Comment: Are you making any other modifications to the view at the same time? In my experience that has always made things messy.

Comment: (Basically, split it into 2 rotations of 90° or use Core Animation.)

Comment: JoePasq... Yes.. I am trying to make it "swell":                               theFrame.size.width = 250 * incrementStep;
theFrame.size.height = 250 * incrementStep;                        This is in a loop

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the last example (the removeWithSinkAnimation method) of this tutorial, I could help you: [basic animation](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5478/uiview-animation-tutorial-practical-recipes)